# Can I prevent Android from booting in Safe Mode altogether?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, safe-mode

I have a Nexus 5 (hammerhead) running CyanogenMod 11.

The Volume Down rocker button is damaged in such a way that it's stuck **on** ([apparently a common failure mode after 2+ years](https://protyposis.net/blog/replacing-the-nexus-5-power-button/)).

The only real problem with the device is that it *always* boots into safe mode, due to the stuck button.

Is there any way to disable the Volume Down activation of Safe Mode, so that I can boot my phone into normal, full Android mode?

Comment: Having exactly the same problem (damaged volume buttons and Can't get rid of Safe Mode). Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. :(

Comment: @janthelme, see answer I just added which does the trick. (By fully disabling the <kbd>VOLUME DOWN</kbd> button in Android.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Right way to do this

Disable the broken <kbd>VOLUME DOWN</kbd> key by editing `/system/usr/keylayout/gpio-keys.kl` and `/system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl` as `root` and commenting that key out. Longer instructions [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675185/disable-hardware-keys-home-back-in-android-4-4).

## Dumb and hacky approach that sort of worked for me

This is an ugly solution but it works for me. It is a "tethered" solution requiring `adb` to do repeated "soft reboots" (restarting the [Android Zygote process](http://coltf.blogspot.com/p/android-os-processes-and-zygote.html)).

This `bash` script repeatedly restarts the Android Zygote process until it detects that the device isn't in safe mode. Takes about 20-50 reboots until my device randomly gets lucky and doesn't restart in safe mode…

```
#!/bin/sh
n=0
g=0
while true; do
    safe_mode=$(adb shell dumpsys display | egrep -o 'mSafeMode=\w+' | cut -d= -f2)
    case "$safe_mode" in
    true)
        n=$(( $n + 1 ))
        g=0
        echo "In safe mode, rebooting (try #${n}) ..."
        adb shell "su root -- killall zygote"
        ;;
    false)
        g=$(( $g + 1 ))
        [[ $g -gt 2 ]] && break;
        echo "Appears not to be in safe mode, will check again ..."
        ;;
    *)
        echo "adb shell dumpsys display failed" ;;
    esac
    sleep 15
done

adb shell dumpsys power | grep -q 'mScreenOn=false' && \
    adb shell input keyevent = POWER

echo "Escaped from safe mode after ${n} reboots. Whew."
```

[This related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/166408/how-can-i-check-if-a-device-is-booted-into-safe-mode-from-adb/166432#166432) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35124874/20789) gave me what I needed to figure it out.