# How can I check if a device is booted into safe mode from adb?

Tags: adb, kernel, command-line, safe-mode

Is it possible to use `adb` to detect whether a device is booted into "Safe Mode" or normal mode?

I've looked through the output of `getprop` and other command-line tools and haven't found any good indicator of safe mode, at least not on my N5/`hammerhead` device.

Update: I'm trying to **check** whether or not the device is in Safe Mode, **not** to force it into Safe Mode. Putting the device in Safe Mode programmatically is [relatively straightforward and well-documented](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131188/entering-safe-mode-from-adb-shell).

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this may help: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/131188/186278

Comment: Thanks, that explains how to *force* a device to be in Safe Mode using `adb`… but it doesn't explain how to *detect* if it's in Safe Mode.

Answer (score 3):

Aha! This'll do the trick! Android's [`dumpsys display` command](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/dumpsys.html):

```
$ adb shell dumpsys display|grep mSafeMode
 mSafeMode=true
```